# What percentage of Mac users have OSX Lion or higher?

Tags: macos

I'm working on a web app and the user needs Safari 6.0 or higher which means they need Mac OSX Lion or higher (per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X#Version_10.7%3a_.22Lion.22))

Users can install Chrome in that case, but I'm wondering how much of an "edge case" this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Chitika, in North America, 55% of Macs on the Internet are running Lion or later. Source: [Gotta Be Mobile](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/09/10/ios-6-now-92-iphones-leading-ios-7-launch/)